# Problems to load mvc Partial using Angular2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm trying to create a small app using MVC and Angular2.rc6 based in this [excellent tutorial](http://www.centare.com/tutorial-angular2-mvc-6-asp-net-5/).

I get stuck to use a partial view as templateUrl.
api.flight

```
@Component({
  selector: "mvc",
  templateUrl: "/partial/flights" //C# mvc Partial flights.cshtml
})
```

When my app starts, I saw by the breaking point,  the app loading Home/Index.cshtml and my Partial/flights.cshtml

When I click on the link to load Flights I get this Exception:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   /partial/flights:1:54 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded

but If I change my API.flight to use: template instance  templateUrl. it works.
api.flight

```
@Component({
  selector: "mvc",
  template: "<h1>Works Well</h1>"
})


public class PartialController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Flights()
    {
      return PartialView();
    }
    public IActionResult Message() => PartialView();

  }
```

I don't know if I'm missing something in my MVC routes, or if I make a mistake on angular2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.cshtml` with angular2 component.

use template url like this-

```
templateUrl: "partial/flights"
```

`partial` is your controller name and `flights` will be your action name

And in MVC Controller, you can just simply return partial view like this-

```
public IActionResult flights() => PartialView();
```

**NOTE:** your action name is flight**s** and partial view is flight.cshtml. Try to maintain same naming conventions.

See if this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest Angular 2 if you're using Webpack because Webpack can't find the view to bundle it.  Do you know how to get this functionality working with Angular 2 and Webpack?

Comment: No @TimHardy, I am also looking for same.

Answer (score -1):

Its throwing error because your `templateUrl` is not correct, `templateUrl` should be valid Component Relative URL as below :

```
@Component({
  selector: "mvc",
  templateUrl: "/partial/flights.html"
})
```

Comment: Partial is an MVC controller Action. it doesn't need csHtml. (C#)